# Is there a way to make notifications show conversation settings on Samsung/One UI?

Tags: android, notifications, samsung-mobile

I have a messaging app that supports many of the modern features of Android's notification system. The notifications appear as conversations in the app's Notification settings, where you can change things like priority, sounds, etc.,  for individual people or channels. On emulator (Android 14), in order for a notification to appear as conversation in settings, you have to either:

- Long-tap the notification and change its priority, or
- Long-tap the notification and click on the cog icon that goes to settings.

However, there is a problem with Samsung/One UI devices (at least with S23, also Android 14). When you long-tap the notification, there's no way to change priority, and when you tap on the settings button, the conversation does not appear as a separate category.

Can I do something about it? Is this One UI bug?

(There is in fact a way to force a notification to show as conversation. We support bubbles, so there's a bubble icon on the notification. If the user taps on that, the notification is promoted to a conversation. However, this is quite undiscoverable. And, what about apps that do not support bubbles?)

Comment: One UI 6.1 [disables notification channels by default](https://www.androidpolice.com/one-ui-61-disables-notification-channels/). Do the conversation options come back if you re-enable notification channels?

Comment: I'm on S23 and One UI 6.0 and I don't have this option (yet). I do see notification channels, and I see conversations when I do the bubble trick. It's just so very undiscoverable.